# How can I cut a string in a file after a given pattern?

Tags: bash

I got around 7000 different lines that all start with an often similiar expression. I need to cut everything after X.

I got these lines:

```
        service_description     PING
        service_description     NSClient++ Version
        service_description     Uptime
        service_description     CPU Load
        service_description     Memory Usage physical
  service_description     Druckerserver-Sicherung
  service_description     Hyper-V Host Cluster
```

In the first 5 lines, there is a TAB, the last 2 only got a space.
Between the 2 columns, there is a TAB, the last 2 only got multiple spaces.

If they all were similiar, I would be able to just cut after a certain amount of digits, since it's different, because of the tabs / spaces.

This is what I got:

```
        service_description     PING
        service_description     NSClient++ Version
        service_description     Uptime
        service_description     CPU Load
        service_description     Memory Usage physical
  service_description     Druckerserver-Sicherung
  service_description     Hyper-V Host Cluster
```

This is what I need:

```
PING
NSClient++ Version
Uptime
CPU Load
Memory Usage physical
Druckerserver-Sicherung
Hyper-V Host Cluster
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I set the delimiter to tab or multiple spaces (at least 2):

```
awk -F"\t|  +" '{print $3}' file
```

Output :

```
PING
NSClient++ Version
Uptime
CPU Load
Memory Usage physical
Druckerserver-Sicherung
Hyper-V Host Cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{$1=""}1' file
 PING
 NSClient++ Version
 Uptime
 CPU Load
 Memory Usage physical
 Druckerserver-Sicherung
 Hyper-V Host Cluster
```